# need help in shceduling task in java

Tags: jsp, scheduled-tasks

I am using EJB timer class which is working fine but i want the scheduler to start from 8:15 not 8, how can i do that. here is my code.

```
  @Schedule(minute="0,15,30,45", hour="8-18", dayOfWeek="Mon-Fri",
  dayOfMonth="*", month="*", year="*", info="MyTimer")
```

Comment: Guys please help. do i have to create separate application for this or i can simple add this scheduler in current application.

Comment: Try to add the logic to the body of triggered method, that if there is before 8:15 do nothing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TimeService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

Example

```
    @Schedule(minute="*/3", hour="*")
    public void automaticTimeout() {
        logger.info("Automatic timeout occured");
    }
```

`automaticTimeout` is triggered every 3 minutes